# Type interference issue when Transforming LiveData<Resource<User>> to LiveData<User>

Tags: android, kotlin, type-inference, android-databinding, android-livedata

I'm trying to combine the [Android Architecture GitHub example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) with databinding. To do so, I think I have to add an additional transformation from LiveData> to a LiveData in the [UserViewModel](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt):

```
val userResourceLiveData: LiveData<Resource<User>> = Transformations.switchMap(_login) { login ->
    if (login == null) {
        AbsentLiveData.create()
    }
    else {
        repository.loadUser(login)
    }
}

val userLiveData: LiveData<User> = Transformations.switchMap(userResourceLiveData) { userResource ->
    if (userResource == null) { // Error 1 on 'if'
        AbsentLiveData.create() // Error 2 on 'create()'
    }
    else {
        MutableLiveData(userResource.data)
    }
}
```

However, there are 2 errors showing up:

> 1) type inference for control flow expression failed, please specify its type explicitly.
>
> 2) Type inference failed: not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  create(): LiveData

If I change the code to this:

```
if (userResource == null) {
   AbsentLiveData.create<User>()
}
```

then `switchMap` starts complaining:

> Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter Y in ...

1) Why isn't this working the same? I didn't expect a type definition was required at all, because the mapping for `<LiveData<Resource<User>>>` worked properly in the same way.

2) How to solve the errors?

3) Might this solution to apply databinding be the wrong approach alltogether?

[The commit with this specific issue on GitHub repo](https://github.com/PatrickKuijpers/MyGitHub/commit/ec11419a2221e2bfaa6a84187d2ced6d983f0182)

Comment: `userResource.data` is type `User?`

Comment: What I was trying to say was because `userResource.data`'s type is a `User?`, it returns `LiveData<User?>` so it might not match with the method signature. Have you tried doing something like `MutableLiveData(userResource.data!!)` ?

Comment: You're right, it's a `User?`, however, I don't see any errors on that line. Changing it to a `MutableLiveData(userResource.data!!)` doesn't change a thing. There's only errors on the places I pointed out in comments. You could fork my repo if you need more info.

Comment: If I leave out the complete if-else statement, then I DO need to define it as `MutableLiveData(userResource.data!!)` though. However, the app immediately crashes on that line, because `userResource.data` == null initially!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
        if (userResource == null) {
            AbsentLiveData.create<User>()
        }
        else {
            MutableLiveData(userResource.data!!)
        }
```

Comment: I just found a different solution myself:
```if (userResource?.data == null) {
            AbsentLiveData.create<User>()
        }
        else {
            MutableLiveData(userResource.data)
        }```
I think it's safer compared to a forced `!!`. I noticed it because the `if` statement was the only difference when comparing with the `userResourceLiveData` mapping. Still. I found the solution thanks to your comments, so I'll accept your answer ;-)

Still, I think the error is rather misleading (the latter at least, after I added `<User>` to the `create()`)!